# How to get propery from object Laravel in foreach?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following loop in template:

```
@foreach ($hotel->first()->images as $key => $image)
            // Here I try to get $image->id
@endforeach
```

So, if display object:

```
{{$hotel->first()->images}}
```

It shows:

```
{"id":1,"filename":"5c52f95a48809728c7b4f2af2825cfb8.jpg","size":58349,"extention":"jpg","created_at":null,"path":"uploads","idElement":9}
```

When I try to get access to `$image->id` insise loop I get error.

Comment: Is your model relationship defined as HasOne or HasMany, because it looks like `$hotel->first()->images` returns single object and you can't really loop thru it with foreach

Comment: Do a `get_class($hotel->first()->images)` because I think your `->images` are returned as a `JSON` string.

Comment: It gives me string `App\Upload`

Comment: explain $hotel->first()->images so we can help

Comment: Yes, I use `Has One`, but seems should be hasMany, because my hotel has many images

Comment: I have resolved this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Has One, you just need to get your variable, you dont need to use foreach.

```
echo $hotel->first()->images->filename;
```